# Sending Integer Value From Arduino Transmitter to Raspberry Pi Receiver Using NRF24L01+pa

Tags: raspbian, gpio, nrf24l01

I am currently stuck in getting the integer value from Arduino to Raspberry Pi using NRF24L01+pa. Here are my codes

arduino.ino (transmitter)

```
#include <RF24Network.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>

RF24 radio(10, 9);

RF24Network network(radio);

const uint16_t home_node = 00;
const uint16_t distant_node = 01;

struct payload_t {
  byte ID;
};

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SPI.begin();
  radio.begin();
  
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX); // Set the power amplifier level to the maximum
  radio.setChannel(0x76);
  radio.openWritingPipe(0xF0F0F0F0E1LL);
  const uint64_t pipe = 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL;
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipe);

  radio.enableDynamicPayloads();
  radio.powerUp();
  radio.setPayloadSize(32); // Set the payload size to 32 bytes
  network.begin(/channel/ 92, /node address/ distant_node);
}

void loop(void) {
  byte ID = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    payload_t payload = {ID};
    RF24NetworkHeader header(/to node/ home_node);
    bool ok = network.write(header, &payload, sizeof(payload));
    if (ok) {
      // Check the signal strength
      delay(100); // Wait for signal strength to stabilize
      radio.startListening();
      unsigned long started_waiting_at = micros(); // Wait here until we get a response, or timeout (500ms)
      bool timeout = false;
      while (!radio.available() && !timeout) {
        if (micros() - started_waiting_at > 500000) {
          timeout = true;
        }
      }
      uint8_t len = radio.getDynamicPayloadSize();
      char rssi_char[len+1]; // create a character array to hold the received payload
      radio.read(rssi_char, len); // receive the payload into the character array
      rssi_char[len] = '\0'; // add null terminator to the end of the character array
      
      if (radio.testRPD()) {
        int16_t rssi_int = random(120, 127); // generate random value between 120 and 127
        Serial.println(rssi_int);
        char rssi_str[6]; // create a character array to hold the converted value
        itoa(rssi_int, rssi_str, 10); // convert the integer to a character array
        radio.write(rssi_str, sizeof(rssi_str)); // send the character array as payload
      } else {
        Serial.println("Less than 64dBm.");
      }
    }
    delay(5000); // Wait between signal strength checks
  }
  delay(15000);
}
```

vs code raspberry pi (receiver)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from lib_nrf24 import NRF24
import time
import spidev

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pipes = [[0xE8, 0xE8, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1], [0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1]]

radio = NRF24(GPIO, spidev.SpiDev())
radio.begin(0, 24, 100000)

radio.setPayloadSize(32)
radio.setChannel(0x76)
radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_1MBPS)
radio.setPALevel(NRF24.PA_MAX)

radio.setAutoAck(True)
radio.enableDynamicPayloads()
radio.enableAckPayload()

radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0])
radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipes[1])
radio.printDetails()
radio.startListening() # start listening for incoming messages

while True:
    while not radio.available(0):
        time.sleep(1/100)

    receivedMessage = []
    radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())
    print("Received: {}".format(receivedMessage))

    print("Translating our received message into Unicode characters...")
    string = ""

    for n in receivedMessage:
        if (n >= 32 and n <= 126):
            string += chr(n)
    print("Value: {}".format(string))

    # convert received RSSI value to an integer
    rssi_int = int(string)
    print("Received RSSI value: {}".format(rssi_int))

    # send a response to the Arduino with the received RSSI value
    radio.stopListening()
    radio.write(str(rssi_int).encode())
    print("Sent response: {}".format(rssi_int))
    radio.startListening()

    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Raspbian is ambiguous. What OS are you using?

Comment: 1) You have not asked a question. 2) You have not explained what is happening.  3) You have not explained what should be happening.